# Jquery mobile styling issue

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, styling

I using jQuery mobile to make a site and for some reason it won't let me put a textbox and a button on the same line.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Message" id="usermsg" /><input type="button" value="Send!" id="submitmsg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried resizing the textbox to make room for the button, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using **grids** is the correct way to do this.

```
  <label for="points">Textbox and a Button on the same line.</label>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
            <input type="text" data-inline="true" placeholder="Your Message" id="usermsg" />
      </div> 
     <div class="ui-block-b">
            <input type="button" value="Send!" id="submitmsg" data-inline="true"/>
     </div>
   </div>
```

If you want to change the grid size you can simply add some css to the it. eg. `class="ui-block-a myField"` 
Also as a quick suggestion, I would recommoned staying away from using IDs in JQuery Mobile due to the AJAX navigation. It is recommended to use classes instead.